# geometric shape in css, filled up with content

Tags: html, css

[example picture : is it even possible?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mebTv.png)
Hello everybody. I really stuck with the problem:
Have: 4 links with icons. (like menu)
Need: place them all into the shape. Which one would be adaptive while scaling and doesn't let the content go out of shape.
Tried (btw 2 weeks already trying): css generators, rotations, compiling rectangle and triangle, pseudoelement ":after". But the result is nothing.
 p.s. I'm the only begginer, and may be something obvious for experts like you I'm just missing, that's why I'm asking.

my code

```css
 .item{
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 12%;
    transform:  scaleY(-1);
}
.linkiconsize img{
    height: 50px;
}


/*ICON BG SHAPES */
.trapezoid {
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    width: 50%;
    top: 12%;
    border-top: 0 solid;
    border-right: 35px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border-bottom: 61px solid black; /* white required */
    border-left: 0 solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    -o-text-overflow: clip;
    text-overflow: clip;
    -webkit-transform:  scaleY(-1);
    transform:  scaleY(-1);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
            <!-- bootstrap -->
        
            <div class="wrapperpos trapezoid">
             <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row no-gutters align-items-center item">
                    <div class="col-6 col-md-2">
        
                        <a href="#">
        
                            <div class="linkiconsize">
                                <img src="img/wdep.png"/>
                            </div>
        
                            <span class="">
                        Web development
                    </span>
        
                        </a>
        
                    </div><!-- web dev -->
        
                    <div class="col-6 col-md-2">
        
                        <a href="#">
        
                            <div class="linkiconsize">
                                <img src="img/app.png"/>
                            </div>
        
                            <span>
                        Mobile applications
                    </span>
        
                        </a>
        
                    </div><!--mobile applications-->
        
                    <div class="col-6 col-md-2">
        
                        <a href="#">
        
                            <div class="linkiconsize">
                                <img src="img/seng.png"/>
                            </div>
        
                            <span>
                        Service engineering
                    </span>
                        </a>
        
                    </div><!--service-->
        
                    <div class="col-6 col-md-2">
        
                        <a href="#">
        
                            <div class="linkiconsize">
                                <img src="img/bsn.png"/>
                            </div>
        
                            <span>Business analysis and audit</span>
                        </a>
        
                    </div><!--business-->
        
                </div><!-- row with no gutters + link's positions-->
                    </div><!--container -->
                    </div> <!--wrapper-->
```

Comment: Not the only way by any means, but definitely doable with `clip-path` css property (caveat: this property is not widely supported across browsers). It may be a lot easier to create a div with e.g. a`nav` class, style it with this property, then have your `<a>` elements within it. You can find the documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could possibly acheive this using the `skew()` transform. See this guide for possible uses of `skew()` to create various shapes. https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

If you take a look at the 'Parallelogram' and 'Chevron' examples, you can see how the transform allows you to create the cut angle you are looking for.

For this use, you'll probably want the containing element to remain a square, while you create an `.trapezoid:after` declaration and apply the `skew()` to it.